# datevalue function for savesetting not giving the correct format?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to convert a `Savesetting` string value to a date value--delimited by `\`'s. When I convert it via datevalue function, it gives me `12:00:00AM` instead of the saved inputted date of `03.30.20`, which is added in a prior module.

Here is my code:

```
Option Explicit
Dim strfiledate As String
Sub edits_formatting()
    Dim wbk As Workbook: Set wbk = ThisWorkbook
    Dim wsInputs As Worksheet: Set wsInputs = wbk.Sheets("Inputs")
    strfiledate = GetSetting("'HR_METRICS_TEMPLATE_v3.xlsm'", "Update_New_Data", "FileDate")
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Dim filedate As Date
    filedate = DateValue(GetSetting("'HR_METRICS_TEMPLATE_v3.xlsm'", "Update_New_Data", "FileDate"))
    wsInputs.Range("B1").Value = filedate
    wsInputs.Range("B1") = Format(filedate, "m/d/yyyy")
```

is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Side note: when asking VBA questions, please also include a tag for the host application, e.g. Excel, thanks.

Comment: Are you just trying to get the date the file was last saved?

Comment: @BigBen the getsetting used to store the date I input through a prompt `03.30.20`, and it would save that date for use in all modules. Then I needed to format the `.` delmiters to a forward slash, but I couldn't get it to convert, so I attempted to do that through the datevalue function and then the rest

Comment: So you're modifying the registry earlier with `SaveSetting`?

Comment: @bigben I think so? a prior module is prompting an input box, delimited by `.`. That string variable is saved globally by `SaveSetting`. The last thing I want to do is format an input like `03.30.20` to `3/30/20`. You can see my attempt up above, but once I declare `filedate = datevalue(GetSetting(....`, it coverts the `03.30.20` to `12:00:00AM`

Comment: Can you share the `SaveSetting` call for context?

Comment: `SaveSetting "'HR_METRICS_TEMPLATE_v3.xlsm'", "Update_New_Data", "FileDate", strfiledate` is what's in my main module, and then the call for it is above in my post

Comment: @BigBen here is a more complete view of my main module for those variables: 
`Dim strfiledate As String: strfiledate = InputBox("Please Enter Data Folder Date (mm.dd.yy) Include 0's: ", Default:=Format("mm.dd.yy"))`
    `SaveSetting "'HR_METRICS_TEMPLATE_v3.xlsm'", "Update_New_Data", "FileDate", strfiledate` I know that it would be easy to just update the input box setting, but the folders that reference that filedate would also need to be changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've experienced, `DateValue("03.03.20")` returns `12:00:00 AM`.

`Replace` the periods `.` with forward slashes `/` before calling `DateValue`:

```
Dim temp
temp = GetSetting("'HR_METRICS_TEMPLATE_v3.xlsm'", "Update_New_Data", "FileDate")
temp = Replace(temp, ".", "/")
filedate = DateValue(temp)
```